# How I can make NSUserDefaults for each user of my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I need make access to UserDefaults in my app. But I need save settings for each user, who was registered in app. For example:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] setObject:@"15:00" forKey:@"lastTime"]// for current user1
```

and after logout user1 and login user2:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] setObject:@"11:00" forKey:@"lastTime"]// for current user2
```

And, if I try read key @"lastTime", then I get the last value, but not for this user. I can store userDefaults in differentFiles, as an a variant? Or other solutions?

UPDATED:
Finally I solved this problem:

```
#define UserDefaults  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
#define uKey(key)  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",key,User.user_name]


[UserDefaults setInteger:lastData forKey:uKey(@"lastResultDataId")];
```

Comment: are you using json??

Comment: Just create a key that contains the users username. Such as the key would be something like `uk.co.myapp.username.lastTime` or like has been suggested use JSON to store your data

Comment: Using sqlite database with json

Comment: You did not define which platform your question relates - is it iOS, macOS, tvOS, watchOS or all.... there is a fundamental difference between these platforms regarding "multi-user" and its meaning, and so the answers are highly platform dependent.

Comment: Sorry. I mean iOS target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of users on iOS (yet). Each device, an iPhone or iPad, is presumed to have one and only one user. Obviously that's often not true, especially on an iPad, so some apps create schemes for different people to use the device. If you've done that -- and it's not clear that you have -- then you know the username. If you are writing a Mac app then use NSUserName() to get the name of the logged-in user. After that just concatenate the username onto the key from your NSUserDefaults, something like this:

```
NSString *username = @"john";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"15:00" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"last_login_username_%@", username]];
```

(username would set either to NSUserName() for a Mac app or whatever scheme you've come up for a multiuser iOS app)

Comment: Actually, there ARE users on iOS just as they are on macOS - only the iPhone/iPad does not allow you to create more than one user, and the "system" users and groups operate without your intervention.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of user identifier, use a dictionary for the different users:

```
NSDictionary *user = @{@"lastTime": @"15:00" };
[[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] setObject:user forKey:@"userId"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have some way to uniquely identify the user, then just use whatever that is - UUID, username, email, userId - in the key when setting / getting the `lastTime` value

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use a `NSDictionary` like and have a dictionary per user and store that into `NSUserDefaults` under a key constructed out of their username similar to below.

```
NSMutableDictionary *userDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *username = "myUsername";
NSDate *currentDateTime = [NSDate date];

[userDict setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
[userDict setObject:currentDateTime forKey:@"lastAccessed"];

/* Any other user date you want to store about this user
 * Note we are going to use NSUserDefaults which is not
 * secure so do not store sensitive data in here
 */

 NSString *userDictKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uk.co.yourAppName.%@", username];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userDict forKey:userDictKey];
 [[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And to retrieve this data all you'd need to do is know what the users username is and do

```
NSString *userDictKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uk.co.yourAppName.%@", username];
NSDictionary *userRetrievedDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:userDictKey];
```

However if you want to make any amendments to this data you'll need to adapt it so that the data is moved into a `NSMutableDictionary` so you can update it and then store it back into `NSUserDefaults`

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that after setting value, user going to synchronise the userdefaults.
like

[[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: Great advice, but it should be posted as a comment to the question or an edit to an answer with a code sample.

Comment: @TomaszBąk It shouldn't be an edit to someone elses answer. This is a valid answer, incorrect but valid still.